# Geometry Node Curve to Mesh is not working

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I'm currently modelling a bridge. I drew a bezier curve then tried to use the *Curve to Mesh* geometry node to make a rectangular beam out of it.

It didn't work both with curve primitives nodes nor with object info nodes referencing curves placed in my scene. I know that I can achieve the same result by going in the *Object Data Properties > Geometry > Bevel* then using a curve object as my profile, but I'd like to make it with geo nodes.

I would then simply have a panel of options that I can tweak every time I have to make a beam.

[image: Here is my failing setup]

[Here's my scene](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e6tENEaArPWjDSQu77W1nn4SQ6HVJOi8/view?usp=sharing)

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: You still have to bevel it even in geometry nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a another modifier before geometry nodes in your curve object, in this case a *Mirror* modifier.

Most modifiers operate only on mesh data. Even though you can use them on curve objects they actually operate on the mesh derived from the bezier curve, rather than the bezier data itself, and as such output mesh data, rather than a curve.

In your case the input on the *Curve to Mesh* node is already a mesh (that the mirror modifier is producing), rendering it unable to operate, as notified by the info bubble in the top right corner of the note.

[image]

If you add a *Mesh to Curve* node you will see that the result is as expected.

[image]

Comment: That's it ! Thank you very much, I understand now better how some modifiers works.